# Rank, group and set a label in Spotfire table

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I have two column [Clients] and [Sales], I'd like to create a new column containing a scoring (from 1 to 5) for each "Client" in terms of Sales.
I want to make a ranking of [Sales] and split it, uniformly in 5 groups, then set a label 1 for the highest [Sales], 2 for the second group, etc...
Does someone have an idea of an expression to use ?

Comment: please provide some sample data and an expected result; otherwise it's not clear what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

You can use the percentile function in conjunction with a case statement. In the screenshot below, I created 5 calculations to find the 20th, 40th, 60th, and 80th percentiles and then created a case statement to rank based on those values.

Percentile calculation:

```
Percentile([Sales],20)
```

Case statement:

```
case  
when [Sales]<[20th Percentile] then 1 
when ([Sales]>=[20th Percentile]) and ([Sales]<[40th Percentile]) then 2 
when ([Sales]>=[40th Percentile]) and ([Sales]<[60th Percentile]) then 3 
when ([Sales]>=[60th Percentile]) and ([Sales]<[80th Percentile]) then 4 
when [Sales]>=[80th Percentile] then 5
else NULL
end
```

See attached screenshot
[Data sample and calcs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuVBN.png)

Comment: That's exactly what I want, thank you soo much JulieBMA!!